# I am trying to confirm the user through the token but its showing an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I don't have much knowledge about MERN full stack. Here I have a route in nodejs that gets token from react front end and it simply marks "isVerified = true" after finding the desired user in mongoDb. But instead I am getting error that says my promise is getting rejected. I have no idea whats causing it. I have attached the code below. Kindly help me through this out.

I have tried multiple things like changing request body etc. But nothing worked for me.

This is the action where route is being called.

```
export const verifyUser = (verifyEmail, token, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post(`/api/users/confirmation/${token}`, verifyEmail)
    .then(res => history.push("/login"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

Here is my react form that ask for email input and then verifies it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { verifyUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import TextFieldGroup from "../common/TextFieldGroup";

class Confirmation extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      errors: {}
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const verifyEmail = {
      email: this.state.email
    };

    this.props.verifyUser(verifyEmail, this.props.token, this.props.history);
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="confirmation">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">User verification</h1>
              <p className="lead text-center">Enter your email to verify</p>
              <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.email}
                />
                <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Confirmation.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { verifyUser }
)(withRouter(Confirmation));
```

And here is the router

```
router.post("/confirmation/:token", (req, res) => {
  Veri.findOne({ token: req.body.token })
    .then(token => {
      if (!token) {
        errors.email =
          "We were unable to find a valid token. Your token may have expired";
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
      }
      User.findOne({ _id: token._userId, email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          errors.email = "We were unable to find a user for this token";
          return res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
        if (user.isVerified) {
          errors.email = "This user has already been verified";
          return res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
        // Verify and save the user
        user.isVerified = true;
        user.save().then(user => res.json(user));
      });
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("Promise Rejected");
    });
});
```

Comment: You should log the reason for rejection in catch and try to analyse what's happening. Atleast paste the err here.

Comment: you've set up your `confirmation` route to read `query param` but in your route body you're reading from `req.body`. Change that to `req.param.token`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've set up some Express middleware that parses query variables into `req.body`, token is never read. `req.body` should be an object with only one field: `email`. Your query parameters are found in the `req.params` object. It would stand to reason that the promise `Veri.findOne({ token: req.body.token })` will pass `null` to its callback function or outright reject. In any case, it does not have the desired effect. Changing the first query to `Veri.findOne({ token: req.params.token })` should fix the main issue.

It could also be the case that you don't have a body parser middleware in your Express app. If not, `req.body` will be undefined and trying to access fields in it will cause a `TypeError`. Make sure you're using a body parser to populate `req.body`.

Lastly, it could be that the `errors` object is `undefined`. Even if it isn't, it's considered bad practice to mutate such an object. Instead of a line like

```
errors.email = "... error message"
```

write

```
const errors = { email: "... error message" }
```

or keep it as is and initialize errors as an empty object at the top of your handler.

```
router.post("/confirmation/:token", (req, res) => {
  const errors = {}
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thankyou for your kind help. I have now defined an error field and error is gone but now it is not taking token from prams. It is showing "null" for token when I try to console.log the token from prams after the promise.

Comment: You may be sending `'null'` instead of the token from your frontend. Most likely the `token` prop of the Condition component is undefined or null. Set its prop type to `string.isRequired` to check for that.

Comment: Yes, I did a syntax mistake and because of that, null was passing to the backend instead of the token. Thank you for your help.